# calculate the sum of proper divisors of a given number in Racket BSL

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, racket-student-languages, dr.racket

Design a Racket function named `ﬁndProperDivisor` that takes a natural number and calculates the sum of all its proper divisors. A proper divisor of a natural number is the divisor that is strictly less than the number.

Examples:

Input: `20`

Output: `22`

//Proper divisors: `1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 = 22`

```
(define (sum-of-proper-divisors n i)
  (cond [(= i 1) 1]
        [(= (remainder n i) 0)
         (+ i (sum-of-proper-divisors n (sub1 i)))]
        [else (sum-of-proper-divisors n (sub1 i))]))
```

I found this code on this page but it gives me `1+2+4+5+10+20=42` I need `22`.

I would like to write this code with one parameter by using recursion and `cond`. I am using Beginning Student Language (BSL), which does not have things like `let` defined.

Comment: What do you mean by `let` is not defined? Which language are you using?

Comment: beginning student language

Comment: Okay, then consider adding the [racket-student-languages] tag, and saying in your question that you are using Beginning Student Language

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: understand what the code is doing.  Why is there an additional parameter?  What is happening with it?

Step 2: How do you call this?  What does this mean for `i`?

Step 3: What would you have to do differently so that the remainder is not checked against the number itself?

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill the condition `strictly smaller than itself`, call it with `(sum-of-proper-divisors 20 (sub1 20))` then you get `22`, since then, 20 is not counted as divisor.

Since you should define that function with just one number as argument, - due to the constrains of this beginner-language, I would define the desired function as a second function:

```
(define (sum-of-proper-divisors n i)
  (cond ((= 1 i) 1)
        ((= (remainder n i) 0)
         (+ i (sum-of-proper-divisors n (sub1 i))))
        (else (sum-of-proper-divisors n (sub1 i)))))

(define (findProperDivisors n)
  (sum-of-proper-divisors n (sub1 n)))

(findProperDivisors 20) ;; => 22
```